# Run application on Azure Storage emulator error

Tags: java, eclipse, azure-deployment

Trying to run java application from eclipse on Azure Storage Emulator but statup.cmd keeps giving me that error and startup is failing

[image: Fig]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you mean the compute emulator? I don't see anything related to the storage emulator in the screen capture.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT im running an azure deployment project on emulator and get this error before accessing the compute emulator

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you are deploying to the compute emulator without accessing it. I've added the compute emulator tag to this question. Could you also update the question to clarify that this isn't related to the storage emulator?

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT I am running the hello world azure deployment project on eclipse and i press the button to run it on azure storage emulator . I have initialized the emulator and im getting this Azure Startup failed [2] exiting error

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΔημητρίου Please refer to the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator#storage-emulator-command-line-tool-reference) to startup the emulator manually via console. Any concern or update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I ve already started the emulator using this tutorial before i run the application on it

Comment: Great, it sounds like everything is fine with the storage emulator. Based on the screenshot, it appears that your role's startup script is failing. Can you debug further to determine which line is failing?

Answer (score 0):

[this is my .startup.bak file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5orn.png)

@MichaelRoberson-MSFT i uploaded an image of it